# How can I disable only Zoom out functionality in a scrol lview in Swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, mobile-application, swift2

I am using pinch zoom for the image I have placed over the scroll view. I want to disable the only zoom out functionality and keep the zoom-in functionality. I have used this code but it is not working.

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,sampleView.bounds.size.width,sampleView.bounds.size.height)
scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.bounces = false
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
scrollView.contentSize = screenshot.size


scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

imageView = UIImageView(image: screenshot)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,sampleView.bounds.size.width,sampleView.bounds.size.height)
imageView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: Can the user zoom out after zooming in though?

Comment: @kennytm ... yes it should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And, finally found the solution after a great struggle :

```
scrollView.bounces = false
scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
```

We can disable zoom-out functionality and can have zoom-in functionality by setting the bounces and bouncesZoom properties to false. We can set MaximumZoomScale property to whatever value we want.